# FileNameExtensionFilter adding file filters repeatedly

Tags: java, swing, filechooser, filefilter

I have a file chooser demo like below, Assume I have coded inside browseButton.addActionListener()

```
FileFilter docx = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Word file(.docx)", "docx");
FileFilter doc = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Word file(.doc)", "doc");
FileFilter pdf = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Pdf file(.pdf)", "pdf");
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(docx);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(doc);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pdf);
chooser.setFileFilter(docx);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
int ret = this.chooseLeft.showOpenDialog(chooserFrame);
if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
try{
File leftFile = this.chooseLeft.getSelectedFile();
leftfileName =  leftFile.getName().toLowerCase();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I click browse button first time it looks perfectly, but in 2nd time the file filters added with existing filters. Ho to avoid that!! Any help please. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So, I assume if you have an instance field called `chooser`, so each time the `ActionListener` is called, it reconfigures the dialog over and over again.  Instead, configure it once and simple re-use it

Comment: Either you should add filter only on creation or recreate chooser each time it should be shown

Comment: yes you both correct... Thanks buddies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I assume if you have an instance field called `chooser`, so each time the `ActionListener` is called, it reconfigures the dialog over and over again.  Instead, configure it once and simple re-use it

```
private JFileChooser chooser;
//...
protected JFileChooser getFileChooser() {
    if (chooser == null) {
        chooser = new JFileChooser(...);
        FileFilter docx = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Word file(.docx)", "docx");
        FileFilter doc = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Word file(.doc)", "doc");
        FileFilter pdf = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Pdf file(.pdf)", "pdf");
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(docx);
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(doc);
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pdf);
        chooser.setFileFilter(docx);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    }
    return chooser;
}
//...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = getFileChooser();
    int ret = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooserFrame);
    if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        try{
            File leftFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            leftfileName =  leftFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically an example of lazy loading, where the `JFileChooser` isn't created until it's actually used, but it gets re-used as needed, which makes it faster